# clojure functions, let & return values

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, idioms

Is it unwise to return a var bound using let?

```
(let [pipeline (Channels/pipeline)]
  (.addLast pipeline "codec" (HttpClientCodec.))
  ;; several more lines like this
  pipeline)
```

Is the binding here just about the lexical scope (as opposed to def) and not unsafe to pass around?

**Update**
In writing this question I realised the above was ugly. And if something is ugly in Clojure you are probably doing it wrong.

I think this is probably the more idiomatic way of handling the above (which makes the question moot, btw, but still handy knowledge).

```
(doto (Channels/pipeline)
  (.addLast "codec" (HttpClientCodec.)))
```

Comment: `doto` doesn't really make this question moot, because the version of your code using `doto` expands to the same thing as your original version. But it *does* tell you that it must be perfectly okay to do this, or else `doto` wouldn't be written this way!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, and why I left the question answer here for future generations :D. The idiomatic expression reveals the underlying structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`let` is purely lexically scoped and doesn't create a var. The locals created by `let` (or `loop`) behave exactly like function arguments. So yeah, it's safe to use as many `let`/`loop`-defined locals as you like, close over them, etc. Returning a local from the function simply returns its value, not the internal representation (which is actually on the stack, unless closed over). `let`/`loop` bindings are therefore also reentrancy/thread-safe.

By the way, for your specific code example with lots of java calls, you may want to consider using `doto` instead or additionally. http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doto

Comment: I almost beat you to the "doto" :P